# Manhwa where the main character goes looking for his teacher's daughter after his teacher is killed

Tags: story-identification, manga, cultivation

The main character (MC) and his teacher train in a cave for some years, before the teacher dies. After that, the MC goes looking for his teacher's daughter. I think the MC's teacher cultivates heavenly celestial general cultivation.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Did the MC have long hair or short hair? Also, did the MC's teacher die from natural causes, or was he murdered?

Comment: From what i remembere mc has two friends (1girl 1boy)when some group come takes the girl and leaves the mc to die tied up, a elderly person comes takes him as disciple, and they fight his teacher enemy, the teacher gets injured after which they gets sealed in a cave for some years where the teacher dies after getting out of there he goes looking for his techer daughter.hope thus helps

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for **Memoir Of The God Of War** by Woo-Gak.

> Breathing does not guarantee everyone’s alive! Dan Sa Yu, a descendant of Goryeo, greatly reprimands the Central District for the sake of his friend whom he treasures the most. He reigns every battle! No one could stop him! Cheonpo Armed Forces. The greatest martial arts of Goryeo! The legend of Cheonpo Armed Forces lives on while the history of the King of War unfolds!

> The main character (MC) and his teacher train in a cave for some years

[image: The MC getting out of the cave]

> After that, the MC goes looking for his teacher's daughter

[image: The MC's teacher asks him to look for his daughter]

> I think the MC's teacher cultivates heavenly celestial general cultivation.

[image: The name is the Heavenly Artillery General]

Comment: Thank you very much good sir

Comment: You're welcome @Cis, could you mark the answer as the accepted one to close the question?